# Why std::get does not work with variables?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am running into a trouble of understanding how functions, especially template functions and local variables behave during the compilation time.

So this code works well with `std::get`:

```
enum class UserInfoFields{name, email, address};

using UserInfo = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>;

int main()
{
    UserInfo s{"Edmund", "edmund@page.me", "Denver street 19"};
    std::cout << std::get<static_cast<size_t>(UserInfoFields::name)>(s) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This from my understanding is because `std::get` is a template function and it requires a template argument to be known during the compilation. That makes sense as `static_cast<...` gives us the value during the compilation time.

What I do not understand, if I change the `main()` code to this:

```
 int main()
{
    UserInfo s{"Edmund", "edmund@page.me", "Denver street 19"};
    auto a = static_cast<size_t>(UserInfoFields::name);
    std::cout << std::get<a>(s) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is not allowed. I know that I have to use `constexpr` but I want to know, why exactly the second code does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template non-type parameters, like the `size_t` that `std::get<>` takes, must be compile time constants.

Your `auto a` is not a compile time constant.  In your specific case, you can prove that the value `a` has at that point will never vary and always be `0`.

But C++ is a strongly typed language that relies on explicit types provided by the programmer.  At the point where `std::get<a>` is evaluated, the only thing C++ permits itself to know about `a` is that it is a non-const non-constexpr local variable of type `std::size_t`.

Thus if `std::get<a>` works, so must:

```
int main(int argv, char ** argc) {
  UserInfo s{"Edmund", "edmund@page.me", "Denver street 19"};
  std::size_t a = argv; // number of arguments
  std::cout << std::get<a>(s) << std::endl;
}
```

`std::get<std::size_t>` is a `nothrow` function, and it is not permitted to fail at runtime.  If you call this code with 100 arguments, the above code cannot possibly work.

Second, while your `UserInfo` is 3 identical types, `std::get<size_t>(tuple<a,b,c>)` works when the types are not the same.  So

```
using UserInfo = std::tuple<int, std::string, double>;
```

then `std::get< argv >( some_user_info )` also has to work.  And in this case, the type it returns can be any one of three types -- but C++ demands that all expressions have *one* type.

The short version is "the language standard says so".  The longer version is "In the general case, your code doesn't work".

Now, you can solve your code in your specific case with a few changes.

```
using UserInfo = std::array<std::string, 3>;
```

now `UserInfo` is known to have 3 uniform types.

```
std::cout << s[a] << std::endl;
```

and now you pass in the index, and as the argument to `[]` isn't a template non-type parameter, it can vary at runtime.

`[]` is permitted to execute UB if the index is out of bounds.  (`std::get<a>` is not).

Now, the C++ could evolve and the new standard could throw some magic and somehow detect your special case and permit std get to fail at runtime etc.  But then every call to `std::get` is a possible runtime failure, while before it was not; the testing surface of your application just exploded.

Heck, it could auto-detect that `auto a = blah` was initialized with a constant expression on the previous line, and make its use on the next line automatically be a constant expression.

But then a programmer who knew what they are doing who replaced a call to `get_proper_a()` with `3` for debugging could have their code spuriously change behaviour as secret type information "leaks" into the code.  And when `get_proper_a()` which actually returns `3` (but the compiler cannot prove it) runs, the code breaks at runtime.

Comment: So why someone would want to create a template function with a template argument? If it is easier to make a template function with a function argument?

Comment: @aikhs the static type of the return value of a function cannot depend on function argument values.  It can depend on template non type template argument values.

Answer (score 6):

You wrote yourself that

> `std::get` is a template function and it requires a template argument to be known during the compilation

The value of a local variable is *not* (in the general case) known during compilation; a local variable's value is a runtime property. As such, a local variable cannot be used as a template argument.

If you want to use it as one, you have to make it a compile-time value. This is achieved by making it `constexpr` (as you've also stated in the question).

Comment: After you writing it down I feel so stupid... I don't know but my brain refused to accept that local variables are not known during the compilation time and I didn't even go to read about that because I thought I am right.

Comment: I have a question, if I take a simple template function:
```template<typename T>
auto to_size_t(T index)
{
    return static_cast<size_t>(index);
}```


And write in the main ```int f = 4; std::cout << to_size_t(f);```
Why does this work? If f is a local variable

Comment: @aikhs In this case of `to_size_t`, the local variable `f` is used as a *function* argument, which is perfectly fine. *Template* arguments must be compile-time constants. If you had written `template <int v> auto to_size_t() { return static_cast<size_t>(v); }`, you wouldn't have been able to use `f` there either.

Comment: BTW, `const auto a = 0; std::cout << std::get<a>(...)` also works.

Comment: @Angew Ok I see, this is because template arguments should point or copy some argument value otherwise template argument will be hanged during the compilation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a formal explanation, but rather a (hopefully) easy to understand rationale.

As C++ is a strongly typed language, the return type of `std::get` has to be known to compiler at compile time. But different versions of `std::get` would return different types - because there could be different types in the tuple at different indexes.

Because of that, value to the template argument of `std::get` needs to come from somewhere which is known to compiler at compile time. constexpr variable is something which has a value known to compiler, as well as, for example, `const` variables initialized with constant expressions. But simple non-const integral variable, even when initialized at definition, is not.